# predicate logic in clause form

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

can somebody tell me how to convert a formula to its corresponding clause form step by stepi?

$¬(∀x∃y P(x,y) → (∀y∃z ¬Q(x,z)∧∀y¬∀z R(y,z))$

i know the formua has to be transformed into cnf fisrt
im a bit confused on the first step which is to transform the original formula to rectified form. my teacher told me the only thing i have to do is to check if there is any same variable with quantifiers. then rename it. is it true?
can somebody answer the above question step by step so i can watch and learn??

Comment: This might help: http://www.mathcs.duq.edu/simon/Fall04/notes-7-4/node2.html

Comment: can somebody tell me why do we have to negate the formula first???
i thought if we negate the formula then the original formula would not s-equivalent to the cnf form of it.

Answer (score 1):

See Mordechai Ben-Ari, *Mathematical Logic for Computer Science* (3rd ed - 2012), page 174.

In order to get the CNF for a *closed* formula of f-o logic, we have to :

> Step 1: Rename bound variables so that no variable appears in two quantifiers
>
> Step 2: Eliminate all binary Boolean operators other than ∨ and ∧
>
> Step 3: Push negation operators inward, collapsing double negation, until they apply to
>   atomic formulas only.
>
> Step 4: Extract quantifiers from the matrix. Choose an *outermost quantifier*, that is, a
>   quantifier in the matrix that is not within the scope of another quantifier still in
>   the matrix. Repeat until all quantifiers appear in the prefix and the matrix is quantifier-free.
>
> Step 5: Use the distributive laws to transform the matrix into CNF.

Now with your example : rename bound variables :

> $\lnot (∀x∃yP(x,y)→(∀v∃u¬Q(v,u)∧∀w¬∀zR(w,z)))$ --- I suppose that $∀y∃z¬Q(x,z)∧...$ is a misprint for $∀x∃z¬Q(x,z)∧...$

remove $\rightarrow$ [we have tu use the equivalence between : $p \rightarrow q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$] :

> $\lnot (\lnot ∀x∃yP(x,y) \lor (∀v∃u¬Q(v,u)∧∀w¬∀zR(w,z)))$

push $\lnot$ inwards [we have to use (more than one time) De Morgan laws and the equivalence between $\lnot \forall$ and $\exists \lnot$, etc. and, of course, double negation] :

> $∀x∃yP(x,y) \land \lnot ((∀v∃u¬Q(v,u)∧∀w∃z\lnot R(w,z)))$

and again :

> $∀x∃yP(x,y) \land (∃v∀uQ(v,u) \lor ∃w∀zR(w,z))$

Then we have to move the quantifiers upfront :

> $∀x∃yP(x,y) \land (∃v∀u∃w∀z(Q(v,u) \lor R(w,z))$
>
> $∀x∃y∃v∀u∃w∀z(P(x,y) \land (Q(v,u) \lor R(w,z)))$.

Comment: why do we have to negate the formula first? i thought the first step is to rename the bound variable. i use the book "logic for computer scientist"

Comment: according to the book the steps are as following:

1. find the rectify form by renaming the bound variable.
2. substitute the free variables
3. produce the prenex form
4. eliminate the "∃" quantifier
5. convert the matrix of step 4 into cnf

Comment: can you explain me why does the formula has to be negate on the first step.

Comment: @user146955 - the context is to proof a formula $\varphi$; in order to do this, the semantic tree method try to find an interpretation showing that $\lnot \varphi$ is satisfied; if so, being $¬φ$ satisfiable, we conclude that $φ$ is valid. Having said that, forget of step 1; starting from $φ$, in order to produce the CFN is right to follow the step in tour book. I'll amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: im still a bit confused."∀x∃yP(x,y)→(∀v∃u¬Q(v,u)∧∀w¬∀zR(w,z)) --- I suppose that ∀y∃z¬Q(x,z)∧... is a misprint for ∀x∃z¬Q(x,z)∧..."  you still take a negation on step 1. i dont really understand it. why is it needed?

Comment: ok. i get this. last question. on the step of renaming the bound variable. what is the tips of this step? my teacher told me that the only thing i have to concern is to check if there are 2 or more different Qx (Q is a quantifier) with same variable. and i dont have to concern about the free variable? can you explain this to me? like what is the algorithm(tips) of this step. thanks you alot

Comment: @user146955 - about the quantifiers, we can in principle avoid the "change" **all** bound vars, but if we do that, we cause no harm. The change is needed in order to avoid errors. If we have e.g. $\forall xE(x) \lor \forall xO(x)$, this is **not** equivalent to $\forall x(E(x) \lor O(x))$ : it is true that each number is Even **or** Odd, but for sure it is **not** true that all numbers are Even or all are Odd. The same with $\exists$ and $\land$ : $\exists xB(x) \land \exists xW(x)$ is not equivalent to $\exists x(B(x) \land W(x))$; 1/2

Comment: @user146955 - if we have a Black ball and a White ball, it is not true that we have a ball that is Black-and-White.

Comment: ex: ∀xE(x)∨∀xO(x) if we want to convert this to prenex form ,i have to rename the bound variable. so the formula is now ∀xE(x)∨∀yO(y). the reason that i can rename the bound variable is coz the bound variable does not represent any particular element but any element of ground set(see p.47). so,if the rename the bound variable, i can have the quantifiers to the left of the formula with the rule 2 on p52. also in the above example i can also rename it and turn the formula to ∀wE(w)∨∀yO(y) then change it to skolem form and use the algorithm to check if it is unsatisfiable. am i right?

Comment: @PawanHsu - Exactly ! we rename them, in order to have them distinct. The reason why we can do it is that $\forall xP(x)$ and $\forall yP(y)$ and $\forall zP(z)$ and ... all "means" the same thing, i.e.that $P$ holds for **all** obects. Variables bounded by quantifiers "work" as the $dx$ in the *integral*

Comment: hanks man. your explanation is just awesome. i think i get the idea of it. one more stupid question to see if i dont lost. "unlike propositional logic, there is infinite structure for every formula in predicate logic" this sentence is true. 1.am i right? im always wondering in what case that a formula could be valid. i know for sure there are some formulas that are valid(that is the reason we learn herbrand theorem to have the semi-decidablity). but i just cant come up with any formula that is valid. 2.can you give me an example? thanks man. you really help me alot on this topic

Comment: @PawanHsu - a formula in f-o logic is called *valid* when it is true in every *interpretations* [check for *semantic* of predicate logic : page 44-on]. In f-o logic with *equality* a trivial *valid* formula is $\forall x(x = x)$. A less trivial one (usually used as axiom for f-o logic) is $\forall xP(x) \rightarrow P[x/t]$; if $P$ holds for all objects, for sure it will holds also for the objects "named" $t$ [$t$ is a *term*, i.e.it is a "name" for some objects : in number theory the *numerals* $\overline 0$, $\overline 1$, ... are names for the numbers $0, 1$, ... 1/2

Comment: @PawanHsu - We have that $∀xP(x)→P[x/t]$ is *valid*, i.e. is *true* in every interpretation; consider now the interpretation with $\mathbb N$ as domain (i.e.the set of natural numbers); and consider as interpretation of the predicate $P$ the following : $x \ge 0$; finally, consider the term $1$. Our formula will be : $\forall x(x \ge 0) \rightarrow (1 \ge 0)$; it is obviously true and it is so because it is an "instance" of a *valid* formula.

Comment: I mean for every formula in predicate logic. it has infinite structures. for example, P(x,y) can be interpreted as predicates like {x>y} or {x>y+1}or{x>y+2} and so on. P(x,y) itself is only a predicate symbol without any meaning. By given it a structure it gets its meaning(i.e a truth value). Hence, a valid formula in predicate logic means that it is true under any structure(infinite). and because that we can not test all those structure(becasue it has infinite so it is undecidable), so we have to apply those theorem we learn to obtain a semi-decidablity)  am i right? thanks.

Comment: @PawanHsu - Yes. In prop logic there are algorithms (the oldest and inefficient is: truth-tables) to test for *tautology*. In f-o logic, due to the infinity of possible interpretations, we have to limit ourselves to partial solution. Thus the importance of *proof systems* (like Hilbert-style or natural deduction) which "generate" theorems (due to soundness, they are valid formulae). But for a "complicated" and unknown formula, if we are currently unable to find a proof, we do not know in advence if a proof exists : this is the semi-decidibility.

Comment: sorry man i might be a little bit annoying. i got few questions on this. 1.Does the quantifiers in a formuala has commutative property? in the example in page 53. i also obtain the example the answer ∀x∃z∃w ¬(Q(z)∧¬P(x,y)∧P(f(a,w)))and also other answers with other permutation of the quantifiers. i read the textbook and seems like my answer might be also correct. but i always thought that ∀x∃zP(x,z)is not equivalent to ∃z∀xP(x,z) can you explain me why does the quantifier has commutative property in this example?

Comment: 2. i cant get the point of the definition in p.54. in what situation that we have to do the substitution?(the above def in p54). i dont understand "By [x/y] a substitution is described. In the following, we treat substitutions as independent objects, describing a mapping from the set of formulas to the set of formulas". what does that mean "independent objects" and describing a mapping from the set of formulas to the set of formulas" i thought there is only one formula is substituted. and also in the end of this definition. it says that "t1 can contain occurrences of y" what does that mean?

Comment: @PawanHsu - Please, note thet Ex page 53 says that : that $\forall x \exists yP(x, y)$ is a consequence of $\exists u \forall vP(v, u)$, but not vice versa. You are right; $\forall \exists$ do **not** commute: in $\mathbb N$ it is true that $\forall x \exists y(x < y)$ but it is **not** true that $\exists y \forall x(x < y)$. This shows us that $\forall x \exists y(x < y) \nvDash \exists y \forall x(x < y)$, i.e.that $\exists y \forall x(x < y)$ is not consequence of  $\forall x \exists y(x < y)$. 1/2

Comment: 3. ∀x(¬∃xP(x,y)->∃xQ(x,x)) im asking to find the skolem form of this formula. but this formula is kinda weird. i apply the equivalence rule and obtain ∀x(∃xP(x,y)∨∃xQ(x,x)). and im going to rename the "x" variable but there are "∀x" and "∃x" so i get the answer ∀x(∃wP(w,y)∨∃zQ(z,z)). i know i might do it wrong on this step(rename the bound variable). can u show me how to do it in this situation ? sorry man. i might have too much question. but i want to learn this real bad for the future study of knowledgebase system. if you can answer me, i'll be really appreciating.

Comment: the reason that the example on p53 can have it quantifiers commute is that all the variables belong to different predicate symbols. that is what i thought. am i wrong?

Comment: @PawanHsu - the Exercise says that : $∀x∃yP(x,y)$ is a consequence of $∃u∀vP(v,u)$. First, check it in $\mathbb N$ with $\ge$ in place of $P$; it is true that $∀v(v \ge 0)$ (thus an $u$ such that ... exists) and is also true that $∀x∃y(x \ge y)$: it is enough to assume $0$ as $y$. In general, if we have *one* $u$ which stand in the relation $P(u,v)$ with every $v$, then for every $x$ we may pick-up this obeject and we have found an $y$ such that is in the relation $P(x,y)$ with $x$. 2/2

Comment: @PawanHsu - about Example page 53: please, read the bottom line of the page. In general you cannot swap $\forall$ and $\exists$ (see my comments above). But you may swap $\forall x \forall y$ with $\forall y \forall x$, and the sane with a "double" $\exists$. The restrictions is with multiple quantifiers on the same "predicate"; as you have noted, having "rectified" the formula (see page 55) the swapping causes no harm.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14278/discussion-between-pawan-hsu-and-mauro-allegranza)

Comment: @PawanHsu - about susbstitution, page 54. The mechanism of $F[x/t]$ is very simple; if $F(x)$ is $(x > 0)$ and $t$ is a term "naming" the number 1 (we will use $1$ as term), then $(x > 0)F[x/ 1]$ will be : $(1 > 0)$. Saying that the subst : Set_of_Formulas $\rightarrow$ Set_of_formulas, he simply means that a correct subst into a well-formed formula gives as ouput a new correct formula.